# alpine failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com

Tags: command-line, email, alpine-mail

When I try to send email from alpine I get the following error:

> Error sending: connection failed to gmail-smtp...

(The message disappear before I have the time to copy it).

I suspect this is a firewall issue (I'm in a university campus). How can I fix this (or at least confirm)?

Edit:

I tried to telnet:

> yotam@sumsum:$> telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
>
> Trying 209.85.229.109... telnet:
>
> Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try connecting directly to the SMTP port on the server via telnet? See the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) for an illustrative example. Start with the following (for a SMTP connection at port to smtp.gmail.com at port 25). Replace with the server and port you are using. In the following, `EHLO` and `HELP` are typed at the client prompt, as part of the SMTP negotiation. Note that the server response TO `HELP` is to point you to a copy of the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP).

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying 74.125.53.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP k9sm2692779pbc.22
EHLO
250-mx.google.com at your service, [59.183.41.125]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
HELP
214 2.0.0 http://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=RFC+2821 k9sm2692779pbc.22
```

If you can get this far, I suspect you don't have connection issues. Just one question to clarify. Is Alpine trying to deliver your mail directly, or are you handing off the mail delivery to a local mail server eg. Exim or Postfix? I have all my mail handed off to Exim, and then Exim sends it to a smarthost, which seems the preferred thing to do for hosts that don't have a static IP address at least. One advantage of the latter approach is that you can look at your mail server logs and/or queue to see what is happening with your mail.

Comment: Isn't gmail using port 587 for smtp? http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287

Comment: Right. I just added "Replace with the server and port you are using."

Comment: @Yotam: You do need to specify the port to whatever agent you are using to deliver the mail.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: I'm pretty sure I do. Any way I used alpine in the way describe here http://wijeyesakere.com/tech/tech/alpinemail.html

Comment: @Yotam: Yes, that is sending mail directly from Alpine. I don't recommend this. You are better off delivering to a local mail server (for all sorts of reasons). This is a misfeature in my opinion, MUA should not be doubling as MTAs. I used to do it that way (I've used Pine/Alpine since 1994), and I switched to delivering to Exim because it was just much better.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: You suggest I'll send my email to another service running on my machine and this service will talk to google?

Comment: @Yotam: Yes, the mail server running on your machine. You'll need to learn a little about mail servers. The leaders are exim/postfix. You can find information about both on the net, including this site. Unfortunately the [Exim book](http://www.uit.co.uk/BK-EOGR4/HomePage) is proprietary. I'm not sure about Postfix, which I don't use.